# In WinRT XAML, how to reference images in outside/separate assembly/project?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

Seems to be different in WinRT (Windows 8). 
Anyone figure it out yet?

**My experiments.**

Of course:

File Build Action == Content && Copy to Output Directory == Copy always

These don't seem to work:

```
<Image Source="Folder/file.jpg" />
<Image Source="/Folder/file.jpg" />
<Image Source="Namespace;Folder/file.jpg" />
<Image Source="Namespace;/Folder/file.jpg" />
<Image Source="pack://Namespace;Folder/file.jpg" />
<Image Source="pack://Namespace;/Folder/file.jpg" />
```

Out of desperation I tried:

File Build Action == Embedded Resource && Copy to Output Directory == Copy always

**Still fail.** Ugh!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<Image Source = "ms-appx:///<projectName>/<folderName>/<contentName>" />
```

For example ...

```
<Image Source = "ms-appx:///ClassLibrary1/Content/myimage.png" />
```

See [How to Reference Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965322%28v=win.10%29.aspx) for a bit more info.

Comment: Yeah, sorry ... I couldn't find the XAML version :(

Comment: The XAML version hasn't been published yet, but if you do this in code, it's "Files/" and then the path you would normally use. Or at least that's what I discovered using the ResourceManager.

Comment: How would you do this from code-behind or viewmodel?

Comment: @JayKannan (and google) your `Image`'s `Source` would be bound to a `Uri` property in your ViewModel